# Maximum no of device that can connect to BLE(BluetoothGattServer) server android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, android-ble

Does anybody knows the maximum number of device that can be connected to ble peripheral ? I tried with two devices and it connects well but the third device is not able to connect to  Android BLE peripheral/ BluetoothGattServer. Is there any limitation ?

I did googled a lot but didn't get any answer for BLE peripheral limit ?

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check [Android Lollipop: Bluetooth LE Matures](https://newcircle.com/s/post/1697/android_lollipop_bluetooth_andevcon): "Maximum number of connections is 7 in Android 4.4 and further". Check also this https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68538: "I am able to connect simultaneously 6 peripherals".

You can also digg Google's issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=2&q=-has:defect%20attachments=0%20BLE&colspec=ID+Status+Priority+Owner+Summary+Stars+Reporter+Opened&groupby=&sort=&x=&y=&cells=tiles&mode=grid

Comment: Thanks, for the answer but  I guess it is device specific With Moto G 3rd gen I am able to connect - maximum 2 device and with Nexus 5x I am able to connect 3 device as I have 3 Test device to check with it

Answer (score 1):

Even though the Android source code offers a hint on a theoritical maximum, the truth is that it is entirely dependent on hardware capabilities. For example, with the Nexus 6p, I'm able to achieve about four simultaneous connections before experiencing timeout errors (status 133) and random disconnections. On the other hand, a low end device like the Moto E 2nd gen will only support two connections.